# How do you apply dictionary values in arithmetic expressions involving a list of equal-length dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have a list of dictionaries.

```python
list_of = [
    {"A": 2, "B": 1, "C": 5},
    {"D": 1, "E": 9, "F": 1},
    {"G": 1, "H": 2, "I": 8}
]
```

I want to multiply each value in the dictionaries in the list by the values defined in a second dictionary. *Assume that all dictionaries are of equal length.*

```python
dict2 = {"A": 1, "B": 1, "C": 5}
```

**Output should be:**

```python
list_of = [
    {"A": 2, "B": 1, "C": 25},
    {"D": 1, "E": 9, "F": 5},
    {"G": 1, "H": 2, "I": 40}
]
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? Your attempt *doesn't even compile*. It isn't at all clear what you are trying to accomplish, particularly, what is the result you expect.

Comment: To get an updated list of dictionaries

Comment: Please be *specific*. It is not clear what the output you expect to get is. There's no reason for us to guess, you can just tell us.

Comment: The output is each value of the dictionaries in the list gets multiplied by each value of dict2 by their corresponding index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have dictionaries with different keys (but equal *lengths*), if you want to multiply each value in each dictionary by a multiplier (ignoring key matches), you could do the following.

```python
list_of = [
    {"A": 2, "B": 1, "C": 5},
    {"D": 1, "E": 9, "F": 1},
    {"G": 1, "H": 2, "I": 8}
]

dict2 = {"A": 1, "B": 1, "C": 5}
multiplier = list(dict2.values())

for dictionary in list_of:  
    for key, n in zip(dictionary, multiplier):
        dictionary[key] *= n

print(list_of)
```

#### Output

```
[{'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 25}, {'D': 1, 'E': 9, 'F': 5}, {'G': 1, 'H': 2, 'I': 40}]
```

Comment: Instead of writing that `multiplier` separately, you can also use `dict2.values()`.

Comment: Might be neater to use `for key, n in zip(dictionary, multiplier): dictionary[key] *= n`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the suggestion. Answer updated.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that changes the result though, because it then matches by key rather than by position in the dictionary.

Comment: @Ghostkeeper Using `zip` in this fashion does not change the result in Python 3.7+, since dictionaries are guaranteed to maintain the ordering of their key-value pairs.

Comment: @Ghostkeeper the behavior would be the same as the original version either way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multiply *by position* then this will only really work in versions of python where dictionaries are ordered (Python 3.7+).

```
import operator as op

list_of = [
            {"A": 2, "B": 1, "C": 5},
            {"D": 1, "E": 9, "F": 1},
            {"G": 1, "H": 2, "I": 8}
          ]

dict2 = {"A": 1, "B": 1, "C": 5}

vals = dict2.values()

list_of = [
    dict(zip(d, map(op.mul, d.values(), vals)))
    for d in list_of
]
```

I used `map(op, d.values(), vals)` because I think this is one of the example of where `map` is more readable than a list comprehension. Consider:

```
>>> import operator as op
>>> xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> ys = [5,4,3,2,1]
>>> list(map(op.mul, xs, ys))
[5, 8, 9, 8, 5]
```

Vs:

```
>>> [a*b for a,b in zip(xs,ys)]
[5, 8, 9, 8, 5]
```

Particularly when used with the `dict` constructor along with `zip`